# Create an array of Firebase References with common routines for Listeners

Tags: swift, firebase

I'd like to create an array of Firebase Instances each that have listeners that fire off the same routine.

For example: Assume data is stored at root as such:

```
https://someapp.firebaseio.com/chatrooms/RoomFoo/John/...
https://someapp.firebaseio.com/chatrooms/RoomFoo/Mary/...
..
..
https://someapp.firebaseio.com/chatrooms/RoomBar/Alice/...
https://someapp.firebaseio.com/chatrooms/RoomBar/Bob/...
```

Members inside each room have a listener (childAdded and childRemoved) for each user also in that room

Lets say Adam joins RoomFoo, the following happens:

- Adam gets the current data
- Adam sets Listener at user John and user Mary : in case these users
  add or remove data under themsleves
- Adam sets Listener at RoomFoo, so he can process any new user that
  joins

Similarly:

- John and Mary have their listener at RoomFoo fire off for a new user
  (Adam) who just joined
- John and Mary set listeners for Adam to process data Adam adds or
  removes under him

If I build an array of Firebase references I am able to add/remove references to this array and set listeners too, but these listeners never get called!

This is how the array is declared (Swift)

```
var allUserRef : [Firebase] = []
```

The logic that appends a reference to this array and sets listeners

```
func userJoinedRoom(snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) {
        print(snapshot.key + " Joined!")
        let firebaseRootRef = Firebase(url: firebaseRootUrl)
        let roomsRootRef = firebaseRootRef.childByAppendingPath(roomsRelativePath)
        let userRoomRef = roomsRootRef.childByAppendingPath(snapshot.key)
        //read initial data as well : TODO
        allUserRef.append(userRoomRef)
        print(allUserRef) //Works great - i can see a list of references
        userRoomRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: userAddedData)
        userRoomRef.observeEventType(.ChildRemoved, withBlock: userRemovedData)
    }
```

The problem is that userAddedData and userRemovedData never get invoked

What is my mistake?

Comment: What is the reason for not just setting an observer on /chatrooms instead of having dozens of separate observers? If /chatrooms is observed, any time a user or the users data is added (or changed), the app will be notified and if that newly added user is in the same room as the current user then take whatever action is needed (update UI with their name for example), otherwise ignore the event. It could be taken down one level and just observe the room the user is in instead of all users (up one level) or the individual users (down a level)

Comment: Oh, and why are you keeping an array of references? Once you add an observer, it 'sticks' to that node until you remove it. If you still need those 'references' for removing observers, you may want to look into Firebase handles and keep those in an array:  var handle = ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in...

Comment: Hi Jay, well the reason I intend to have an observer per user is because a user may be generating/modifying large amount of content under its root. As I understand it, a firebase listener on the room-name will not provide me with only the new/changed data, but instead the entire contents in the tree below it, thereby requiring me to figure out at the client side, which data is new/changed. Hence the motivation to create separate observers. Is this something you do not recommend? Can you suggest how I handle my above dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by maintaining the handles in dictionary (indexed by userid) instead of the Firebase instances as Jay pointed out in the comments